# How to sync Azure Devops Repo with Gitlab

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, gitlab

We are using Azure Devops repo for some of our development needs. We are also using gitlab as our main source control. I want to keep my gitlab repo in sync with Azure repo. That is whenever some change is committed in Azure Repo, it should automatically flow to Gitlab. 
We are using GitLab CE, hence mirroring Pull option is not available

Comment: i dont think there is anything built-in for that, but you can always script it

Comment: @4c74356b41 Can you please help me the basic directions, as to how to set it up

Comment: git checkout\commit\push

Comment: Hi, how was the things going? Does the answer below can help you sync the files between Azure Devops and Gitlab?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to use **Command Line Script** task in build pipeline, and then push the update to gitlab via the git command as follow shown.

```
git clone https://gitlab.com/{account name}/{project name}.git
git config --global user.name "XXX"
git checkout master
git add .
git commit -m "abc"
git push https://%pt%@gitlab.com/xxx/xxx.git
```

At first, I restore the value of gitlab token in to the variable, for example **GitlabPAT** and set it as secret. And then add an environment variable: **pt**, set this environment variable value to $(GitlabPAT). 
[image]

In command line task, use double **%%** to get the value of environment variable **pt**.

In addition, for pushing the commits from the azure devops repo to gitlab repo in real time, you can set the Build Triggers as **Enable continuous integration** option.So once the master branch changes, it will trigger CI build, and also your update will be pushed to gitlab repo with these git commands.

[image]