# Clone gitlab repos to Azure Devops and maintain sync on Azure repo

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, gitlab

I imported Gitlab repo to Azure DevOps Repo. If I add any file on my Gitlab repo, it is not reflecting on Azure Devops Repo. If there are many repos under organisation or groups, is there anyway to import all in once and update all imported Azure repo whenever any changes are made on Gitlab repo to have sync on them?

Comment: This might can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57359245/how-to-sync-azure-devops-repo-with-gitlab

Answer (score 0):

> Clone gitlab repos to Azure Devops and maintain sync on Azure repo

I'm afraid there is no such out of way to sync Azure Devops Repo with Gitlab repo.

To sync Azure Devops Repo with Gitlab repo, we could create a service connection for gitlab repo:

[image]

Then use the other git as build resource:

[image]

Add a powershell/command line task to push the code to the Azure devops repo:

```
git commit -m "Update package version"

git push https://<PAT>@dev.azure.com/<OrganizationName>/xxx.git
```

And you can set the Build Triggers as **Enable continuous integration option**. Once any changes are made on Gitlab repo, it will trigger CI build, and this build will be pushed to Azure devops repo with these git commands.

Hope this helps.