# Is there a way to push Azure Repository to Gitlab one?

Tags: azure-devops, gitlab, azure-pipelines, repository, mirroring

There are 2 companies

Company A uses Azure Repos
Company B uses Gitlab Repos

I need to set up repos mirroring
Push Gitlab to Azure and Push Azure to Gitlab. In the first case, it was fairly simple to push Gitlab to Azure, using built-in GitLab function Mirroring.

However, I am struggling to find a way how to push Azure Repo to Gitlab repo.

I have tried creating service connection in Azure Devops project and then creating Azure Pipeline as powershell script (Note: In example below, PATs are random numbers for better visualisation):

Write-Host Starting the synchronization process
mkdir copyrepo
$sourceURL = "https://$(Gl684feafeaag56416agvr)@$(https://gitlab.com/blabla/myproject.git)"
$destURL = "https://$(Az14d4w846acf)@$(https://blabla@dev.azure.com/BlaBla/AzProject/_git/AzProject)"
Set-Location "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/copyrepo"
git clone --mirror $sourceURL
Set-Location "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/copyrepo/$(myproject)/"
Write-Host "*****Git removing remote origin****"
git remote rm origin
Write-Output "*****Git remote add****"
git remote add --mirror=fetch origin $destURL
Write-Output "*****Git fetch origin****"
git fetch $sourceURL
Write-Output "*****Git push to Azure Repos****"
git push origin --all -f

It ends up with: git checkout failed with exit code 1
I have even tried to enable checkout for any nested submodule, but stil getting the same error.

Is this even a good way of approaching the goal to push azure repo to gitlab, or is there a better way ?

Comment: Please, look at this (possible duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57359245/how-to-sync-azure-devops-repo-with-gitlab

Comment: I have tried the described solution, still ending up with
error: pathspec refs/remote/origin/main did not match any files known to git
Git checkout failed with exit code: 1